# What are supposedly the most important macro data to include in a regression analysis in retail?

Tags: regression, macroeconomics

I work in retail and we want to complie a regression analysis to see how different factors impact our business and retail in general.

So far, I have started to educate myself on R (by suggestion from a fellow member here).

We currently analyze promotions, cycles and marketing Campaigns within our own organization and their outcomes.

But I want to create a regression to see how well things correlate and what is the coeffecient of determination. Basically, I want to find out how well I can trust certain conclusions.

Macro factors so far:
-Weather
-Paydays
-Strikes

I'm considering factors such as inflation and real estate (rents).

We have business all over the World so there would eventually have to be an analysis per country.